# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: .../para-answers.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
<?php 
    $options = json_decode($question->answers); 
    $correct_answers = json_decode($question->correct_answers);
    
     $outer_index=0;

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="questions-container fullwidth">
          <?php 
          foreach($options as $option) { 
            // dd($user_answers);
            $cAnswer = $correct_answers[$outer_index]->answer;
            $uAnswer = $user_answers[$outer_index];
            // dd($uAnswer);
            // print_r($option->options[0]);
              $sub_options = (array)$option->options;
              $optionsl2  = null;
              // if(isset($option->optionsl2))
              // $optionsl2 = (array) $option->optionsl2; 


            foreach($sub_options as $key => $value)
             $sub_options = $value;
            ?>  
            <li>
                <div class="question">
                    <h3> <span class="language_l1">{!!$option->question !!}</span>
                     
                    </h3> </div>
               
                <div class="select-answer">
                    <ul class="row">
                    <?php $index=0; 
                     
                     foreach($sub_options as $key1 => $value1) { 
                        $correct_answer_class = '';
                        if($cAnswer==$index+1)
                        {
                              $correct_answer_class = 'correct-answer';
                        }
                        
                        $submitted_value = '';
                        if($user_answers) 
                        {
                           if($uAnswer == $index+1) 
                           {
                                $submitted_value = 'checked';
                                
                            }
                        }
                      
                        ?>
                        <li class="col-md-6 {{$correct_answer_class}} answer_radio" >
                            <input type="radio" name="option{{$question->id.$outer_index}}" id="1radio1"  {{$submitted_value}} disabled="">
                           
                        </li>
                        <?php $index++; } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <hr>
            <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here we got an issue (Cannot use object of type stdClass as array). Please help me to solve this problem.
In this we want to show result of students paragraph questions...
This project build on laravel 5.2 please check the following errors solve this...
I get this error while we take a paragraph exam.

laravel.log file

```
[2022-12-28 10:33:50] production.ERROR: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View:.../exams/results/para-answers.blade.php) (View: .../exams/results/para-answers.blade.php) {"userId":397,"email":"synstek@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: .../exams/results/para-answers.blade.php) (View: .../exams/results/para-answers.blade.php) at .../storage/framework/views/c537d6f89990306206a4616db41781ac8be6132d.php:15, ErrorException(code: 0): Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: .../exams/results/para-answers.blade.php) at .../storage/framework/views/c537d6f89990306206a4616db41781ac8be6132d.php:15, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Cannot use object of type stdClass as array at .../storage/framework/views/c537d6f89990306206a4616db41781ac8be6132d.php:15)
[stacktrace]
#0 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(45): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)
#1 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/finocoin/...', Array)
#2 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(137): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('/home/finocoin/...', Array)
#3 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(120): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#4 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(85): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#5 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(42): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#6 .../vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(199): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#7 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#8 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(698): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#9 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#10 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 .../app/Http/Middleware/AccountStatus.php(50): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\\Http\\Middleware\\AccountStatus->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(67): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(660): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#39 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 .../vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#50 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 .../public/index.php(54): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 .../index.php(20): require_once('/home/finocoin/...')
#53 {main}
```

Comment: Open the laravel.log and copy/paste the error with the entire stacktrace. You can paste it in your original question

Comment: Hi @UnderDog, I updated the laravel log file please check and suggest a solution...

Comment: Which controller is calling para-answers.blade.php ? Open that controller and copy/paste the action that is making this view. The controller is sending data to the view and the data is not an array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Just Replace below two lines 
$options = json_decode($question->answers); 
$correct_answers = json_decode($question->correct_answers);

// With 
$options = json_decode($question->answers,1); 
$correct_answers = json_decode($question->correct_answers,1);
```

Comment: When i do this got other error( Trying to get property of non-object )

Comment: Can you show me complete error Screenshot